# How to Insert a copy of a row (with a new identity) using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a number of tables that together make up a "Test" that somebody can take. There are multiple types (scripts) of Test a person can take. I'm working on an Edit function that will allow somebody to edit the Test Questions. I want these edited questions to show up on all new Tests of that type, but still show the old questions when viewing past test scores.
To do this each "Test" has a `TestId` auto-increment identity (along with its name). When a test is edited I want to make a copy of the test with a new `TestId` and present the questions for editing.

So what is the best way to make the copy and insert it into my table using LINQ to SQL? This:

```
   DataContext db = new DataContext(ConnectionString);

    //Copy old test into identical new test but with a different script ID
    var oldScript = db.TestScripts.Single(ds => ds.TestScriptId == oldScriptID);
    var newScript = oldScript;
    db.TestScripts.InsertOnSubmit(newScript);
    db.SubmitChanges();
```

of course tells me that I `Cannot add an entity that already exists.`

Is the only way to do this to go through every column in the TestScript and copy it manually, then insert it, and the database will give it a new Id?

**Edit**
I've also tried

```
DataContext db = new DataContext(ConnectionString);
//Copy old test into identical new test but with a different script ID
var oldScript = db.TestScripts.Single(ds => ds.TestScriptId == oldScriptID);
var newScript = new TestScript();
db.TestScripts.InsertOnSubmit(newScript);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

hoping that it would make a new empty row, then I could `newScript = oldScript` and submit the changes, but it gives me `SqlDateTime overflow` errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I see two ways for you:

1. Just make a "make copy" function that copies all the attributes over
2. Use reflection to automaticly copy all properties with the [column] attribute over (Thats a little bit hardcore, and can be alittle magical, if you get it to work)

There are some "magic" functions floating around the web, that saids that they can do it, but I would prefer number 1, and have full control myself.

Also: Ask yourself it it's really the right DB schema you are using, the you need to copy an entire tree, if a person makes a change - maybe a DB change, can make this way easier for you?

Comment: Mer. I figured this (1) is what I was going to have to do. Was hoping there was an easier way though. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Is the cloning part overhere what you are looking for?

http://damieng.com/blog/2009/04/12/linq-to-sql-tips-and-tricks-2

Comment: Hrm. This gives me a "contains cycles and cannot be serialized" error. My TestScript entities point to many TestScriptItem entities which point to many TestScriptItemOption entities.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: Ugly hacky untested possibility

How about setting the id to null?

```
newScript.TestScriptId = null
db.TestScripts.InsertOnSubmit(newScript);
```

Comment: I did say it was hacky! Feel free to downvote.Same error by the way?

Comment: Nope. It didn't like that the TestScriptId is an int and I was giving it a null (also tried System.DBNull.Value).